# how to automatically adjust window size to buffer height?

Tags: buffers, window

I want to optimize my `gdb` window setup. The idea is to automatically resize the `gdb-breakpoints` window to the current buffer length. In my setup this buffer is at the bottom and I want it to auto-resize vertically every time I add or remove a breakpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Try function `fit-window-to-buffer`? Put it on an appropriate hook for use with `gdb`.

> **`fit-window-to-buffer`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `window.el`.
>
> `(fit-window-to-buffer &optional WINDOW MAX-HEIGHT MIN-HEIGHT MAX-WIDTH
>   MIN-WIDTH)`
>
> Adjust size of `WINDOW` to display its buffer's contents exactly.
>   `WINDOW` must be a live window and defaults to the selected one.
>
> If `WINDOW` is part of a vertical combination, adjust `WINDOW`'s
>   height.  The new height is calculated from the actual height of
>   the accessible portion of its buffer.  The optional argument
>   `MAX-HEIGHT` specifies a maximum height and defaults to the height
>   of `WINDOW`'s frame.  The optional argument `MIN-HEIGHT` specifies a
>   minimum height and defaults to `window-min-height`.  Both
>   `MAX-HEIGHT` and `MIN-HEIGHT` are specified in lines and include mode
>   and header line and a bottom divider, if any.
>
> If `WINDOW` is part of a horizontal combination and the value of
>   the option `fit-window-to-buffer-horizontally` is non-nil, adjust
>   `WINDOW`'s width.  The new width of WINDOW is calculated from the
>   maximum length of its buffer's lines that follow the current
>   start position of `WINDOW`.  The optional argument `MAX-WIDTH`
>   specifies a maximum width and defaults to the width of `WINDOW`'s
>   frame.  The optional argument `MIN-WIDTH` specifies a minimum width
>   and defaults to `window-min-width'.  Both`MAX-WIDTH`and`MIN-WIDTH`
>   are specified in columns and include fringes, margins, a
>   scrollbar and a vertical divider, if any.
>
> Fit pixelwise if the option `window-resize-pixelwise` is non-nil.
>   If `WINDOW` is its frame's root window and the option
>   `fit-frame-to-buffer` is non-nil, call `fit-frame-to-buffer` to
>   adjust the frame's size.
>
> Note that even if this function makes WINDOW large enough to show
>   **all** parts of its buffer you might not see the first part when
>   `WINDOW` was scrolled.  If `WINDOW` is resized horizontally, you will
>   not see the top of its buffer unless `WINDOW` starts at its minimum
>   accessible position.

Comment: Yeah I already tried a hook, but it doesn't work with `(add-hook 'gdb-breakpoints-mode-hook 'fit-window-to-buffer)`. Sorry for not mentioning.

Comment: In order for that function to DTRT on a hook, the buffer you want to fit the window to has to be current, displayed in a window, and that window has to be selected.